# Including "et al." in my bibliography with \bibliographystyle{plain}

Tags: beamer, bibtex, bibliography

I want to use \bibliographystyle{plain} and cite a software in my Beamer presentation that has a LOT of authors. How can I make my Beamer automatically cite the first author and add "et al." if the number of authors is more than 3?

Here's what the reference in my .bib file (Mybibliography.bib) looks like

```
@software{MNESoftware,
  author       = {Larson, Eric and
                  Gramfort, Alexandre and
                  Engemann, Denis A and
                  Leppakangas, Jaakko and
                  Brodbeck, Christian and
                  Jas, Mainak and
                  Brooks, Teon and
                  Sassenhagen, Jona and
                  Luessi, Martin and
                  McCloy, Daniel and
                  King, Jean-Remi and
                  Goj, Roman and
                  Favelier, Guillaume and
                  Höchenberger, Richard and
                  Brunner, Clemens and
                  van Vliet, Marijn and
                  Wronkiewicz, Mark and
                  Holdgraf, Chris and
                  Massich, Joan and
                  Bekhti, Yousra and
                  Rockhill, Alex and
                  Appelhoff, Stefan and
                  Leggitt, Alan and
                  Dykstra, Andrew and
                  Luke, Rob},
  title        = {MNE-Python},
  year         = 2022,
  publisher    = {Zenodo},
  version      = {1.2.1},

}
```

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\section{Bibliography}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
\tiny



    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{Mybibliography}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Currently, my beamer is displaying all the authors. Can someone please tell me how do I achieve the "et al."?

Comment: Rule of thumb: if your bibtex style does not happen to do exactly what you want, consider switching to biblatex instead. This is much easier to customise.

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need `\usepackage{hyperref}`, beamer already loads hyperref for you.

Comment: Try [tex.se] maybe.